# Connect QPushButton between two classes

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

I have a QListWidget that is in a QGridLayout in my constructor of the Draw class.QGridLAyout contains other elements.

```
Draw::Draw(QWidget *parent):QDialog(parent){

gridlayout=new QGridLayout;
gridlayout->addLayout(hbox,0,0);
gridlayout->addLayout(hbox1,1,0);
gridlayout->addLayout(hbox2,2,0);
gridlayout->addWidget(listWidget,3,0);
gridlayout->addLayout(hbox4,4,0);
this->setLayout(gridlayout);

}
```

When clicking on a QPushButton. I'm calling a slot that filled the QListWidget.

//SLOT

```
void Draw::fillListWidget(){
//item is QListWidgetItem
item=new QListWidgetItem;
item->setSizeHint(QSize(0,50));
listWidget->addItem(item);
//WidgetfillListWidget is an other class with parameters for the QListWidget
listWidget->setItemWidget(item,new WidgetfillListWidget(label1,path));

}
```

In my other class I build the new QWidget to fill the QlistWidget. The QListWidget contains a label, a string and a QPushButton.

```
WidgetfillListWidget::WidgetfillListWidget(QString label, QString p){

instanceDraw=new Draw(this);
QString name = label;
QString path = p;

name1=new QLabel(name,this);
path1=new QLineEdit(path,this);
remove=new QPushButton("remove",this);

hboxlist=new QHBoxLayout;
hboxlist->addWidget(name1);
hboxlist->addWidget(path1);
hboxlist->addWidget(remove);

setLayout(hboxlist);
connect(remove,SIGNAL(clicked()),instanceDraw,SLOT(removeItem()));
}
```

In the Draw class I have the slot that has to delete an item but it does not work

```
void Draw::removeItem(){
listWidget->takeItem(listWidget->row(item));
}
```

Deleting the item does not work. I think it comes from my Draw object in the connect. But I do not understand how to solve the problem. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: `takeItem` removes and returns the item from the given row , then you will have to delete it by yourself `delete listWidget->takeItem(listWidget->row(item));`

Comment: I have a segmentation error. I may have a problem with my instance of the Draw class?

Comment: @Thomas1314 
Why are you adding a QString as a Widget? `path1=new QString(path,this);` `hboxlist->addWidget(path1);`

Comment: @eyllanesc excuse me. I was wrong. It's a QLineEdit ....

Comment: But the problem remains the same...

Comment: @eyllanesc I corrected on the code of my question. I think the error comes from the instance of my Draw class.  But I do not understand how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because the Draw created in WidgetfillListWidget is different from the original Draw, they are 2 different objects.

In this case the solution is to create a clicked signal in `WidgetfillListWidget` that is issued when the `QPushButton` is pressed.

Then that signal is connected to the `removeItem()` method. In it we must obtain the item, but that is not simple, one way to do it is through the geometric position as I show below:

**widgetfilllistwidget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGETFILLLISTWIDGET_H
#define WIDGETFILLLISTWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class QLabel;
class QPushButton;
class QHBoxLayout;
class QLineEdit;

class WidgetfillListWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit WidgetfillListWidget(const QString & name, const QString &path, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
signals:
    void clicked();
private:
    QLabel *lname;
    QLineEdit *lpath;
    QPushButton *premove;
    QHBoxLayout *hboxlist;
};

#endif // WIDGETFILLLISTWIDGET_H
```

**widgetfilllistwidget.cpp**

```
#include "widgetfilllistwidget.h"

#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>

WidgetfillListWidget::WidgetfillListWidget(const QString &name, const QString & path, QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    lname=new QLabel(name);
    lpath=new QLineEdit(path);
    premove=new QPushButton("remove");

    hboxlist=new QHBoxLayout(this);
    hboxlist->addWidget(lname);
    hboxlist->addWidget(lpath);
    hboxlist->addWidget(premove);
    connect(premove, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &WidgetfillListWidget::clicked);
}
```

**draw.h**

```
#ifndef DRAW_H
#define DRAW_H

#include <QDialog>

class QGridLayout;
class QListWidget;
class QPushButton;

class Draw : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Draw(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Draw();
private:
    void fillListWidget();
    void removeItem();

    QGridLayout *gridlayout;
    QListWidget *listWidget;
    QPushButton *button;
};

#endif // DRAW_H
```

**draw.cpp**

```
#include "draw.h"
#include "widgetfilllistwidget.h"

#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

Draw::Draw(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    button = new QPushButton("Press Me");
    listWidget = new QListWidget;
    gridlayout=new QGridLayout(this);
    gridlayout->addWidget(listWidget, 0, 0);
    gridlayout->addWidget(button, 1, 0);
    connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Draw::fillListWidget);
}

void Draw::fillListWidget()
{
    QListWidgetItem *item=new QListWidgetItem;
    item->setSizeHint(QSize(0,50));
    listWidget->addItem(item);
    //WidgetfillListWidget is an other class with parameters for the QListWidget
    QString label = "label1";
    QString path = "label2";
    WidgetfillListWidget *widget = new WidgetfillListWidget(label,path);
    listWidget->setItemWidget(item, widget);
    connect(widget, &WidgetfillListWidget::clicked, this, &Draw::removeItem);
}

void Draw::removeItem()
{
    WidgetfillListWidget *widget = qobject_cast<WidgetfillListWidget *>(sender());
    if(widget){
        QPoint gp = widget->mapToGlobal(QPoint());
        QPoint p = listWidget->viewport()->mapFromGlobal(gp);
        QListWidgetItem *item = listWidget->itemAt(p);
        item = listWidget->takeItem(listWidget->row(item));
        delete item;
    }
}

Draw::~Draw()
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not understand why use another QPushButton "button". Because I want to delete from premove

Comment: @Thomas1314 The "button" is the one you mention that is responsible for calling fillListWidget, you mention it in your question.

Comment: excuse me I saw after asking my question what was the button .... Yes I tried and it works !!!! Thank you very much!!! I thought that to delete an item it just took : listWidget->takeItem(listWidget->row(item))

Comment: @Thomas1314 If you use `listWidget-> takeItem (listWidget-> row (item)`) and you have a lot of items, what would that `item` mean? :)